# 'Recent' shortcut missing in Chromium's download window

Tags: 18.04, chromium, filemanager

'Recent' shortcut is missing in *Chromium*'s window which appears when I want to download or save a file. But it is there when I use *Files*.

How can I add it ? It will be useful and help me to save time.

[image]

Comment: No, I mean the window that opens when I choose where to download a file.

Comment: I have update my question with a picture

Comment: It's missing in Firefox and Falkon as well!